# Batch preprocessing when working on Datasets in keras

Tags: keras, padding

I have some examples of a variable-length data matrix and its associated label and I want to train an LSTM network with it. I know that I should pad the data samples (for example using `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences`) at least for each batch and I did it successfully for feeding the network with numpy arrays, but I don't know how to do it with TFRecord Datasets.

I have a typical reading code for my TFRecord file as follows:

```
featuresDict = {'data': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
                'dataShape': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
                'label': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
               }

def parse_tfrecord(example):
    context, features = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(example, sequence_features=featuresDict)   
    label = features['label']
    data_shape = features['dataShape']
    data = tf.decode_raw(features['data'], tf.int64)
    data = tf.reshape(data, data_shape)
    return label, data

def DataGenerator(fileName, numEpochs=None, batchSize=None):    
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fileName, compression_type='GZIP')
  dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrecord)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batchSize)
  dataset = dataset.repeat(numEpochs)
  return dataset
```

I can parse each example and generate my original data matrix and labels. The DataGenerator function then defines the Dataset and sets the batch and repeat features of that. Then I create a DataGenerator object and use it to fit my model:

```
train_data = DataGenerator(fileName='train.gz', numEpochs=epochs, batchSize=batch_size)
model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch = train_steps, ...)
```

Where can I put the padding function in the code? In general, if I want to do a batch-level preprocessing with dataset API how can I do that?

Comment: In your DataGenerator, `dataset = dataset.batch(batchSize)` makes it look like `dataset` could be exploded get the batch's worth of data; is there some reason you can't perform the operations between there and the `return` statement?

Comment: What do you mean by data explosion? This is just a standard code for adding batch capability to the dataset. I can perform operations there, but they operate on Dataset itself, not a batch of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be to **pad the sequences during preprocessing**, when you write to the TFRecords. Then you could use the same code as above.

But I suggest **[padded_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch)**, it works similar ot the Keras Sequence preprocessing. 
If the dimension is known (padded_shapes being some constant), the sequences are padded to this constant. Else, they are padded to the longest sequence.

Comment: Yes that was what I needed. Thank you.